# Is it possible to control which Teamcity agents are permitted via another project?

Tags: teamcity

I have a setup where I have many projects holding code and a few other project used to run a particular configuration with a defined set of dependencies.

The projects are configured to run against many agents however I would like to restrict what agents should be used via the configuration project.

Example

Config Project has 2 agents

Underlying Projects(s) have 4.

However when I run the config project which has a dependency on the underlying projects, many agents are available to use where I wanted to restrict this to a couple.  I know I can force the dependencies to run on the same agent, but I would ideally like this to include any config project compatiable agent.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use agent pools feature which is available since TeamCity 7.0, read more on it here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+7.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity7.0-AgentPools

Comment: Thanks for this. I am using pools. Problem I am having is I want the dependent projects to use the pools available in the parent project.  Doesn't seem possible afaik.